# Updating wine apps through the package manager

Tags: apt

I have heard a lot about Linux's software management and this one of the reason i am planning to switch to it so I wanted to ask that can we update these wine apps through the package managers bcz most of the stuff i do can't be through linux native software.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you're asking, and the connection with this site isn't obvious either.  Stack Exchange *Unix & Linux* covers Linux (*what you are talking about*) where as this site is limited to Ubuntu, or *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).   There are multiple *package managers* in GNU/Linux, and there are even Ubuntu products/releases that don't use `apt` (ie. *snap* only IoT appliance/device/cloud specialist releases)

Answer (score 0):

Most Windows software is not packaged in a deb, pip, snap, or similar format, so package management tools cannot be used. Package managers are convenient, but not magical.

Windows software is generally designed to use Windows install tools (like .exe or .msi) instead, which are often --but not always-- compatible with Wine.